# Can R-783.3-0.5 DC-DC converter be used with 5V input?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I need to use a DC-DC converter to obtain 3.3V/100mA from a 5V supply. I have a [R-783.3-0.5](https://www.recom-power.com/pdf/Innoline/R-78xx-0.5.pdf) available, but I am not sure if it can work with 5V input.

The datasheet says that the minimum input voltage is 4.75V, but note (5) says: "The R.783.3-0.5 requires Vin>5.5V to meet the Transient Response specifications". I do not understand what it means.

So, can this converter be used with 5V input or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input rating of the `R-783.3-0.5` is 4.75V up to 32V.
So **yes**.

However, transient response from/to 100% <-> 50% and 10% load will **not** meet the given specification of ±75mV and ±100mV. For this 5.5V is required.

In other words, you might shortly get less than 3.2V or more than 3.4V if you have large *load steps* when Vin is below 5.5V.

---

If the 5V is from USB, I'd recommend not using this converter, since USB is allowed to go as low as 4.40V within spec.